# Error 45 'MySqlCommandBuilder' is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I have the following code and I get the following error:

> Error 45 'MySqlCommandBuilder' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.  C:\FactMype\Systems\gtpcomercialElectronic\gtperpcomercial\gtperpcomercial\libraries\vps\connectionvps.vb 87 13 gtperpcomercial.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection




Public Class conexionvps

    Public prueba As String
    Dim conexion As conexionvps
    'CONEXION A MYSQL DATA PARA DESARROLLO DE SISTEMAS
    '..procedure
    'Protected Sub insert_generico(ByVal ParamArray parrParms() As Object)
    '    Try
    '        strNombreSP = prostrNombreTabla & "_insert"
    '
    '           Sql.ExecutenonQuery(strNombreSP, parrParms)
    '       Catch ex As Exception
    '
    '        Throw New System.Exception("Error en insert generico.", ex)
    '
    '    End Try
    'End Sub
    Public Function creartablaproc(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Try
            Dim vector() As String = Split(sql, "\")
            Dim dap As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(vector(0), conexionmysql)
            dap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            If vector.Length > 1 Then
                Dim contador As Integer
                For contador = 1 To UBound(vector)
                    dap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter(vector(contador), vector(contador + 1)))
                    contador = contador + 2
                    dap.SelectCommand.Parameters(vector(contador - 2)).Value = vector(contador)
                Next
            End If

            dap.Fill(ds)
            Return ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return ds.Tables(0)
        End Try
    End Function
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Obteniendo datos a lista, combos, grid
    'Obteniendo datos a lista, combos, grid
    'Function ObtenerDatos(ByVal cadena As String) As DataTable
    '    Dim myDataSet As DataTable = New DataTable
    '    conexion = New Conexion()
    '    Dim conect As New MySqlConnection(conexion.conexionmysql)
    '    conect.Open()
    '    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
    '    adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(cadena, conect)
    '    adapter.Fill(myDataSet)
    '    ObtenerDatos = myDataSet
    '    conect.Close()
    'End Function

    ' Actualizar datos directamente del grid pero con un button
    Public Sub actualizargrid(ByVal consulta As String)
        Try
            Dim bidings As New BindingSource
            Dim cobertura As New DataTable()
            'Dim adaptador As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
            Dim adaptador As New MySqlDataAdapter()
            adaptador.Update(CType(bidings.DataSource, DataTable))
            adaptador = New MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, conexionmysql)
            Dim commandbuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adaptador)

            adaptador.Fill(cobertura)
            bidings.DataSource = cobertura
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Excepcion al leer los datos:" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub actualizargridprueba(ByVal consulta As String)
        Try
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()

            MySqlCommandBuilder cd = New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)


        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Excepcion al leer los datos:" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Cadena de conexion en mysql

    Public Function conexionmysql() As String
        Dim CAD As String
             Dim servergsoft As String = "gtpsoft.com" 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("servergsoft").ToString()
        Dim puertobd As String = "3306" 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("puertobd").ToString()
        Dim usuariobd As String = "gtpsoft" 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("usuariobd").ToString()
        Dim clavebd As String = "asdfd9i#Bpy" 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("clavebd").ToString()
        Dim gsoftbd As String = "gtpsoft_seda" 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("gsoftbd").ToString()

        CAD = "Database=" + gsoftbd + ";Data Source=" + servergsoft + ";User Id=" + usuariobd + ";Password=" + clavebd + ";Pooling=false;Connection Lifetime=1; Max Pool Size=1; Port=" + puertobd + "; default command timeout=40000; Convert Zero Datetime=True"

        conexionmysql = CAD
    End Function
    ' Funciones No Probadas
    ' retorna el numero de registro en mysql
    Private Function numeroRegistrosConsulta(ByVal dr As MySqlDataReader) As Integer
        Dim numeroRegistros As Integer = 0
        Do While dr.Read
            numeroRegistros = numeroRegistros + 1
        Loop
        numeroRegistrosConsulta = numeroRegistros
    End Function
    ' consulta para generar en red
    Public errortransaccion As Integer ' si es 0 todo correcto, si es 1 todo incorrecto
    Public Sub Consultamysql_transaccion(ByRef Consultas As String)
        Try
            errortransaccion = 0
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim Conexion_mysql As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())
            Conexion_mysql.Open()
            Dim transaccion As MySqlTransaction
            Dim comando As MySqlCommand
            'Crear un arreglo de memoria y cargar en cada vector las consultas separadas por punto y coma
            Dim Array_Consultas() As String
            Array_Consultas = Split(Consultas, ";")
            transaccion = Conexion_mysql.BeginTransaction
            For i = LBound(Array_Consultas) To UBound(Array_Consultas) - 1
                comando = New MySqlCommand(Array_Consultas(i), Conexion_mysql)
                comando.Transaction = transaccion
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            transaccion.Commit()
            ' transaccion.Rollback()
            Conexion_mysql.Close()

            'MsgBox("Transacción Finalizada con Exito!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Transacción Procesada")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            errortransaccion = 1
            MsgBox("No se pudo ejecutar la transacción!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error en la transacción")
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Detalles del error")

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Consultamysql_transacciongeneral(ByRef Consultas As String)
        Try
            errortransaccion = 0
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim Conexion_mysql As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())
            Conexion_mysql.Open()
            Dim transaccion As MySqlTransaction
            Dim comando As MySqlCommand
            'Crear un arreglo de memoria y cargar en cada vector las consultas separadas por punto y coma
            Dim Array_Consultas() As String
            Array_Consultas = Split(Consultas, ";")
            transaccion = Conexion_mysql.BeginTransaction
            For i = LBound(Array_Consultas) To UBound(Array_Consultas) - 1
                comando = New MySqlCommand(Array_Consultas(i), Conexion_mysql)
                comando.Transaction = transaccion
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            transaccion.Commit()
            ' transaccion.Rollback()
            Conexion_mysql.Close()

            'MsgBox("Transacción Finalizada con Exito!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Transacción Procesada")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            errortransaccion = 1
            'MsgBox("No se pudo ejecutar la transacción!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error en la transacción")
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Detalles del error")

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public cruderror As Integer

    Public Sub consultacrudmysql(ByRef Consultas As String, ByVal tabla As String)
        Try
            errortransaccion = 0
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim Conexion_mysql As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())
            Conexion_mysql.Open()
            Dim transaccion As MySqlTransaction
            Dim comando As MySqlCommand
            'Crear un arreglo de memoria y cargar en cada vector las consultas separadas por punto y coma
            Dim Array_Consultas() As String
            Array_Consultas = Split(Consultas, ";")

            transaccion = Conexion_mysql.BeginTransaction
            For i = LBound(Array_Consultas) To UBound(Array_Consultas) - 1
                comando = New MySqlCommand(Array_Consultas(i), Conexion_mysql)
                comando.Transaction = transaccion
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

            transaccion.Commit()
            ' transaccion.Rollback()
            Conexion_mysql.Close()

            MsgBox("OPERACION EXITOSA", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "SISTEMA")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            errortransaccion = 1
            MsgBox(tabla + " " + "YA EXISTE", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "VALIDACION")

            'Exit Sub
            'MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Detalles del error")
        End Try
    End Sub
    ' leer datos
    Public Sub leerdato(ByVal consulta As String)
        Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(conexion.conexionmysql)
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(consulta, myConnection)
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        myReader.Close()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub



    'obtener solo un valor en especifico sin cargar a grid directo a la variable
    Public Function ValorDato(ByVal Tabla As String, ByVal MiSelect As String)
        Dim Valor As String = ""
        Try

            Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand(MiSelect, myConnection)

            Dim Da As New MySqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
            Dim Ds As New DataSet
            Dim cont As Integer

            Da.Fill(Ds, Tabla)
            cont = Ds.Tables(Tabla).Rows.Count

            If cont = 0 Then
                Valor = ""
            Else
                Valor = Ds.Tables(Tabla).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
            End If
            Return Valor
        Catch ex As Exception

            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Valor
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function retornarstring(ByVal Tabla As String)
        Try
            Dim cm As MySqlCommand
            Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())
            Dim x As String
            myConnection.Open()
            cm = New MySqlCommand(Tabla)
            'La consulta de la línea anterior debe devolver únicamente un registro
            cm.Connection = myConnection
            If cm.ExecuteScalar() Is DBNull.Value Then
                x = "0"
            Else
                x = cm.ExecuteScalar()
            End If

            retornarstring = x
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox("ERROR INESPERADO, RETORNAR STRING", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERP")
            retornarstring = "0"
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function ValorNumero(ByVal Tabla As String, ByVal MiSelect As String)
        Dim Valor As String = "0"
        Try

            Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand(MiSelect, myConnection)

            Dim Da As New MySqlDataAdapter(Cmd)
            Dim Ds As New DataSet
            Dim cont As Integer

            Da.Fill(Ds, Tabla)
            cont = Ds.Tables(Tabla).Rows.Count

            If cont = 0 Then
                Valor = "0"
            Else
                Valor = Ds.Tables(Tabla).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
            End If
            Return Valor
        Catch ex As Exception

            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Valor
        End Try

    End Function
    ''crear bd

    Public Sub CrearBD(ByVal bd As String)

        Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(conexionmysql())

        Dim Cmd As New MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE " + bd + " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;", myConnection)

        Try

            myConnection.Open()

            With Cmd

                .CommandType = CommandType.Text

                .ExecuteNonQuery()

            End With

        Catch ex As Exception

            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

        Finally

            myConnection.Close()

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried what this Mysql page says to fix my code : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-data-adapter.html but it didn't work. I get the following errors[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's a C#-style variable declaration, not VB.Net. Instead of this:

```
MySqlCommandBuilder cd = New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
```

It needs to look like this:

```
Dim cd As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
```